# Multiplying a text input by selected radio button

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i am new to javascript and having some trouble.

I need my function to take the user input "recserv" and multiply it by the value of the selected radio button, as well as update if the value is changed or the radio button is changed.

Changing the radio buttons seems to work, but I get an error when the "recserv" value is changed.

Thank you for any help!

```
<script>
function yeartot(service) {
    var recserv = parseFloat(document.getElementById('recserv').value);
    document.getElementById("result").value = service*recserv;
}
</script>
<body>

<p>Select the frequency</p>
  <input onclick="yeartot(this.value)" type="radio" name="service" value="11">Monthly<br>
  <input onclick="yeartot(this.value)" type="radio" name="service" value="6" checked> Bi-Monthly<br><br>

 Recurring Service Amount <input onchange="yeartot()" id="recserv" value=0><br/><br/>

  Total for year <input type="text" id="result">
```

Comment: Please share the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const setup = () => {
 const serviceInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="service"]');
  serviceInputs.forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', yeartot));
 const recserv = document.querySelector('#recserv');
  recserv.addEventListener('change', yeartot);

}

const yeartot = (service) => {
    const checkedInput = document.querySelector('input:checked');
    const recserv = document.querySelector('#recserv');
    
    const serviceNumber = parseFloat(checkedInput.value, 10);
    const recservNumber = parseFloat(recserv.value, 10);
    
    const result = document.querySelector('#result');
    result.value = serviceNumber * recservNumber;
}


//load
window.addEventListener('load', setup);
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Select the frequency</p>
  <input type="radio" name="service" value="11">Monthly<br>
  <input type="radio" name="service" value="6" checked> Bi-Monthly<br><br>

 Recurring Service Amount <input id="recserv" value="0"><br/><br/>

  Total for year <input type="text" id="result">
  
</body>
```

Comment: Small correction I forgot with the cleanup: You don't need the service parameter on yeartot anymore. It doesn't matter it's their add this point in the current structure. If you for some reason ever decide to seperate click & change functions than you could use parseFloat(service.target.value, 10) to point out to the input your currently clicked or changed. The best practice however would be using an bubble event by adding the listeners to it's parent. Since this is out of the scope of this question. Here's a jsfiddle as example: https://jsfiddle.net/x7eks469/1/

Answer (score 1):

simply this...

```js
document.getElementById('my-form').addEventListener('input', function () {
  this.result.textContent = parseFloat(this.recserv.value) * parseInt(this.service.value)
})
```

```html
<form id="my-form" onsubmit="return false">
  <p>Select the frequency</p>
  <input type="radio" name="service" value="11">Monthly
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="service" value="6" checked> Bi-Monthly
  <br><br>

  Recurring Service Amount <input name="recserv" value="0">
  <br /><br />

  Total for year <output name="result"></output>

</form>
```

-- adding a form makes things easier if each entry (or output) has a name.
-- using a form element, you do not need to use any ID, and you do not need to see which radio button is checked, you directly take the selected value
-- and do not use a change event but use input event

Comment: Keep in mind output isn't supported for IE & iOS Safari. If no other modifications are needed replace output with <span name="result"></span> and replace the content by calling textContent in JavaScript. Alternatively use the readonly parameter on input on html.

Comment: @JensIngels no Safari iOS support output elements -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output#Browser_compatibility. and span element can't have a name attribute

Comment: @JensIngels Safari (iOS and Mac OS X,) ***Supported HTML** https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/HTMLTags.html

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting `NaN` is because in your `#recserv` element's inline JS, you are not passing any value into the function when calling it. Therefore, you are multiplying with `undefined` which gives you a `NaN` value.

A quick fix to your issue will simply be letting the method itself retrieve the checked value of your input, and removing the need to pass any arguments to it. This is, however, a *quick fix* and I would never recommend using inline JS: check the next example for a proper solution.

```js
function yeartot() {
  var recserv = +document.getElementById('recserv').value;
  var checkedService = +document.querySelector('input[name="service"]:checked').value;
  document.getElementById("result").value = checkedService * recserv;
}
```

```html
<p>Select the frequency</p>
<input onclick="yeartot()" type="radio" name="service" value="11">Monthly<br>
<input onclick="yeartot()" type="radio" name="service" value="6" checked> Bi-Monthly<br><br> Recurring Service Amount <input onchange="yeartot()" id="recserv" value=0><br/><br/> Total for year <input type="text" id="result">
```

---

**Proposed solution**: I suggest that you:

1. Use `.addEventListener` to listen to changes to your input elements. You can use `document.querySelectorAll([selector])` to select the inputs that you want to bind the `oninput` event listener to. The callback will simply invoke `yeartot()`
2. Invoke `yeartot()` at runtime, so that you get calculated values when the document is loaded.

```js
function yeartot() {
  var recserv = +document.getElementById('recserv').value;
  var checkedService = +document.querySelector('input[name="service"]:checked').value;
  document.getElementById("result").value = checkedService * recserv;
}

document.querySelectorAll('#recserv, input[name="service"]').forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('change', function() {
    yeartot();
  });
});

// Also, might want to run the first round of computation onload
yeartot();
```

```html
<p>Select the frequency</p>
<input type="radio" name="service" value="11">Monthly<br>
<input type="radio" name="service" value="6" checked> Bi-Monthly<br><br> Recurring Service Amount <input id="recserv" value=0><br/><br/> Total for year <input type="text" id="result">
```

Comment: @HaydnOleson Glad that it worked for you :) happy to help.

Comment: @MisterJojo And your answer is under the assumption that: (1) OP is wrapping input elements in a `<form>` element, (2) that all `<input>` elements will contribute towards the calculation. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

yeartot method has a parameter and when you use yeartot() in onchange property of input cause undefined value in service parameter.undefined value is not a number and take error.

Answer (score 0):

> Change your script into this

```
<script>
      const input = document.getElementById("recserv");
      const result = document.getElementById("result");
      function yeartot(service) {
        const checkedService = document.querySelector(":checked");
        var recserv = Number(document.getElementById("recserv").value);
        document.getElementById("result").value =
          Number(checkedService.value) * Number(input.value);
      }
    </script>
```